# Maurer-Cartan form

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, dg.differential-geometry

I suppose given a Lie Group ($G$) and its corresponding Lie Algebra ($\mathfrak{g}$) every element in its dual defines a Maurer-Cartan form on the whole Lie Group?

Let $\omega \in \mathfrak{g}^*$ be a Maurer-Cartan form and let $X$ and $Y$ be two elements of $g$ then in what sense are $\omega(X)$ and $\omega(Y)$ "constant functions" on $G$ ? (such that we can write $X\omega(Y)=Y\omega(X) =0$)

Assuming the above one can immediately write the Maurer-Cartan equation, $d\omega(X,Y)= -\frac{1}{2}\omega([X,Y])$

Thinking of $\omega$ as Lie Algebra valued 1-form on the Lie Group and using the fact from linear algebra that $V^* \otimes W = Hom(V,W)$ one can write them as $\omega = \sum _i \omega_i \otimes B_i$ where $\omega_i$ are ordinary 1-forms on $G$ and $B_i$ are a basis on $\mathfrak{g}$. (should there be some arbitrary coefficients in front of every term in the above sum?)

Say $c^i_{jk}$ are the structure constants of the Lie Algebra then I do not understand how the Maurer-Cartan equations can be recast as,

$$d\omega_i = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j,k} c^i_{jk}  \omega_j \wedge \omega_k$$

which apparently can be further recast as the equation,

$$d\omega = -\frac{1}{2} [\omega,\omega]$$

I would be happy if someone can explain how the above two forms of the Maurer-Cartan equation can be obtained knowing the first form which is more familiar form to me.

Also finding the structure constants of a Lie Algebra is not so hard for at least the common ones. Knowing that one fully "knows" the Maurer-Cartan Equation.  Now is there any sense in which one can "solve" this to find out the Maurer-Cartan forms? (I would guess a basis might be obtainable)

Comment: I did not understand what the Maurer-Cartan form was until I worked it out for a matrix group where it is always just the one for GL(n) restricted to the group. After thar the abstract version is a lot easier to deal with. 

Comment: This was one of the things I was looking for. To understand if there is any sense in which once can compute an explicit solution to the Maurer-Cartan equation. I haven't seen anything like that even hinted towards in any book. If you could enlighten about that.  

Answer (score 23):

**Note**: As explained below, there is a clash of nomenclature between what Morita calls a Maurer--Cartan form and what Cartan introduced (which is described in [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurer-Cartan_form), say).

First of all there are two Maurer-Cartan forms: left-invariant and right-invariant.  They are one-forms with values in the Lie algebra.  If we identify the Lie algebra (=left-invariant vector fields) with the tangent space at the identity, then the left-invariant MC form $\omega$ is such that acting on a vector field $\xi$ on $G$ gives for all $g \in G$,
$$ \omega(\xi)_g = (L_g)_*^{-1} \xi_g, $$
where $L_g$ means left multiplication by $g\in G$.  There is a also a right-invariant one-form defined similarly but using right multiplication.

Now suppose that $\xi$ is a left-invariant vector field on $G$. This means that
$$\xi_g = (L_g)_* \xi_e,$$
where $\xi_e$ is the value of $\xi$ at the identity $e\in G$.  In that case,
$$\omega(\xi)_g = (L_g)_*^{-1} (L_g)_* \xi_e = \xi_e,$$
which is constant, since it does not depend on $g$.

Now, as you point out, if $X$ and $Y$ are left-invariant vector fields, then it is immediate that $\omega$ satisfies the structure equation:
$$d\omega(X,Y) = -\omega([X,Y]).$$

Now choose a basis $(e_i)$ for the Lie algebra, so that we can write $\omega = \sum_i \omega^i e_i$, where the $\omega^i$ are one-forms on $G$.  Notice that $\omega(e_i)=e_i$, whence $\omega^j(e_i) = \delta^j_i$.

Applying the structure equation to $X=e_i$ and $Y=e_j$ you see that, on the one hand,
$$d\omega(e_i,e_j)=-\omega([e_i,e_j]) = - [e_i,e_j] = - f_{ij}{}^k e_k,$$
whence
$$d\omega^k(e_i,e_j) = f_{ij}{}^k.$$
But this is precisely the result of applying
$$-\tfrac12 \sum_{i,j} f_{ij}{}^k \omega^i \wedge\omega^j$$
on $e_i$ and $e_j$, hence the identity
$$d\omega^k = -\tfrac12 \sum_{i,j} f_{ij}{}^k \omega^i \wedge\omega^j.$$

To write down explicitly the Maurer-Cartan forms, it is not hard.  You have to compute the derivative of $L_g$ in your chosen coordinates.  It is particularly easy if the group $G$ is a matrix group, in which case you have $\omega_g = g^{-1}dg$ and again you have to compute this in your favourite coordinates for $G$.

---

**Added**

I just realised that I forgot to answer the bit about the second form of the structure equation.  That equation is usually confusing at first because the notation hides the fact that $[\omega,\omega]$ also involves the wedge product of one-forms.  By definition, $[\omega,\omega]$ is the Lie-algebra valued 2-form on $G$ whose value on vector fields $X,Y$ is given by
$$[\omega,\omega](X,Y) = [\omega(X),\omega(Y)] - [\omega(Y),\omega(X)] = 2 [\omega(X),\omega(Y)].$$
If you now take $X=e_i$ and $Y=e_j$, left-invariant vector fields, you see that
$$-\tfrac12 [\omega,\omega](e_i,e_j) = -[e_i,e_j] = -\sum_k f_{ij}{}^k e_k,$$
agreeing again with $d\omega(e_i,e_j)$.

---

**Further addition**

This is in response to one of Anirbit's comments.  In Morita's book *Geometry of Differential Forms*, he calls *any* left-invariant form on $G$ a Maurer--Cartan form.  I don't think that this is standard.  For me, as my answer above, the Maurer--Cartan form is Lie algebra valued.  The two notions of Maurer--Cartan forms can of course be reconciled.  Choose a basis $(e_i)$ for $\mathfrak{g}$ and a canonical dual basis $e^i$ for $\mathfrak{g}^*$.  Let $\omega^i$ be the left-invariant one-form which agrees with $e^i$ at the identity.  Then $\omega = \sum_i \omega^i e_i$ is what I have been calling *the* (left-invariant) Maurer--Cartan form.

While I'm at it, let me explain the nature of my factors of $2$, since that seems also to be in dispute.  For me the wedge product is defined as follows $\alpha \wedge \beta := \alpha \otimes \beta - \beta \otimes \alpha$, without a factor of $\frac12$.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps "particularly easy" is not an accurate assessment of the situation, since this can be quite a lengthy calculation.  In exponential coordinates there are a couple of tricks one could use, but it is usually a pain, especially when the Lie algebra has a large semisimple part.  For nilpotent and solvable Lie algebras it's not so bad.

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful explicit explanation. There is one point that looks a bit unfamiliar to me. Could you clarify as to which calculation are you alluding to in your comment as a "lengthy calculation" ? Do you mean the proof of the formula that $(L_g)_*^{−1}=g^{−1}dg$? I am new to this equation.

Comment: Thanks -- the lengthy calculation I referred to is simply the one one needs to do in order to write down explicitly what the MC forms look like in your chosen coordinate system.  Once you parametrise a group, in the sense that group elements are given in terms of some local coordinates by $g(x,y,...,z)$, say, then $gˆ{-1}dg$, which is the pullback to the coordinate space of the MC forms, can be quite a complicated object.

Comment: I strongly recommend just working in $GL(n)$, where you have natural global co-ordinates. You get the same solutions as you would if you restrict to a subgroup. There is no point in using local co-ordinates for the subgroup itself. That is, as José says, messy, complicated, and painful.

Comment: I also recommend unwinding all the abstract notation (push-forwards, pull-backs, differential forms, etc.) and figuring out what everything is on $GL(n)$ in terms of plain old matrices. I found this exercise to be extremely helpful when I struggled with this stuff.

Comment: Could you recommend me a good book to follow for this? I was learning this stuff from the book by Morita which seems to have little or nothing to say about explicit solving of Maurer-Cartan equations using coordinates.  

Comment: There is no need to find explicit solutions of the Maurer-Cartan equations. Just interpret all the formulas you have, including the Maurer-Cartan equations themselves, in terms of matrices. I don't know any references to offer you.

Comment: Deane: I beg to differ.  In the past I have had to find explicit expressions for the Maurer-Cartan forms.  It depends on the sort of research problem you face, I suppose.  But you are right in that this is not learnt from books.

Comment: @Jose I guess you missed a $\omega$ in the RHS of the first equation and the third equation you typed. Also I think the fourth equation will be $d\omega(X,Y)= -\frac{1}{2}\omega([X,Y])$. This factor of half gets compensated when one evaluates $\sum_{lm}c^k_{lm} \omega^l \wedge \omega^m (e_i,e_j) = c^k_{ij}$ because of anti-symmetry in the bottom two indices of the structure constants. Also I would evaluate $[\omega,\omega](X,Y)=[\omega (X), \omega (Y)]$. 

Comment: @Anirbit: No, there is no $\omega$ missing from the first and third equations.  The Maurer-Cartan form *is* the isomorphism between the left-invariant vector fields and the Lie algebra (thought of as the tangent space at the identity).  I also stand by the factor of 2s, but that may just be my conventions for the wedge product.  I follow Spivak's in Volume 1 of his Differential Geometry books.

Comment: @Jose Shouldn't the first equation read as $\omega(g)[\xi _g]=\omega(e)[(DL_g)^{−1}[\xi _g])]$ Only then do I get a number on two sides of the equation. As you have typed it the RHS evaluates to a vector whereas the LHS evaluates to a number. I am approximately going by what is defined say on end of Page 91 of Shigeyuki Morita's book.

Comment: @Jose I guess there are two ways of defining the Maurer-Cartan form as defined by Morita as elements in the dual of the Lie Algebra and asyou defined them as Lie-Algebra valued one forms on the Lie Group. I guess there should be a way to see why they are conceptually equivalent. 

Comment: @Anirbit: I just looked at Morita and now understand the nature of the confusion.  I'll add something to the answer to address this.

Comment: @Jose: I was talking about not trying to work with explicit *solutions*. Certainly, I believe that the best way to learn and understand the Maurer-Cartan equations is to work with the explicit *formulas* such as $\Omega = A^{-1}dA$ and using this formula to derive the Maurer-Cartan equation $d\Omega + \Omega \wedge \Omega = 0$.

Comment: @Jose Thanks a lot for these recent edits. It does make things more clear. Further when one says that one is looking at ``left-invariant" Maurer-Cartan forms then one means the equation $L_g^* \omega = \omega$ as mappings from $T_hG \rightarrow Lie(G) = T_e G$. (for any pair of $g,h \in G$) It is not hard to show this but while doing it I feel that the Maurer-Cartan form is best thought of as a map from $TG \rightarrow Lie(G) = T_e G$ such that $\omega (g,X_g) = (DL_g)^{-1} [X_g]$ 

Answer (score 3):

The Maurer-Cartan form for matrix groups is very well explained in Santalo's book about Integral Geometry.